# Docker for ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nginx, docker

I have a ruby on rails application in my local machine which has Nginx, Phusion passenger, PostgreSQL, Redis as its associated components.How can I create a docker container with all these software/images?
Is it possible to run a Cron job in Docker container?
I am a starter in docker. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can see [docker compose with rails](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)
2. *Is it possible to run a Cron job in Docker container?* Yes, Docker Containers are isolated Linux systems.